# tomcat logging per context instead of catalina.out

Tags: logging, tomcat8

Using logging.properties and the default tomcat 8 juli (java.util.logging) logging, is there a way to configure logging such that all logging for context ABC goes to log ABC.log instead of ( or in addition to ) catalina.out?

By "context", I mean, for instance, the URL configured via `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost/ABC.xml`, which would let me go to URL `http://domain/ABC`.

If I can just get confirmation that it is not possible with the default logging, that would help.

Comment: How are the web applications generating log messages? Are they using java.util.logging, writing to stdout, something else?

Comment: java.util.logging, which is standard for tomcat ( I think under the hood they use JULI code to add some extra features and handling ).